# Best way of object instantiation as part of a collection

Tags: oop, collections, instantiation

Let's say I'm making a task list application, and let's say that there's a Task class and a TaskList class. Now, what would be the best way to add a Task to the TaskList?

```
new Task(TaskList,"task name")
```

or

```
TaskList.addTask("task title")
```

in the second case, the TaskList would be responsible for instanciating the Task class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for the second option.
However, there could be coupled with  a third option available that allows you to extend the Task class, that is a method with the following signature

TaskList.Add(Task task);

This way you would instantiate the Task class, set all properties, and then add it to the TaskList object.

Ideally, the TaskList.addTask(string taskName) method you defined, could be a helper method that ends up internally calling the third method, and you could leave that method available if you need to support greater flexibility in setting the Task object properties.